# If $g$ is an element of order 27 in $G$, does an element of order 3 exist in $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $g$ is an element of order 27 in a group $G$, does an element of order 3 exist in $G$?

I've been struggling with this for a long time. I've tried Lagrange and I've tried some theorems. I know that it's probably using the factors of 27 which are 1, 3, 9 and 27. How do I do this for every other exercise like this?

Comment: If $g$ has order $27$, $g^9$ has order $3$, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an element $g \in G$ has order 27, $(g^9)^3 = g^{27} = e$, and $g^9 \neq e$ and $(g^9)^2 = g^{18} \neq e$, so $g^9$ has order 3 as requested.